# How to create the magnetic card reader code in php with Ajax call with working code?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm creating a magnetic card reader code to process the data for one of my project in php with Ajax. If anyone have a working code example, please share.

I have connected the device to my project server, I'm using php-7.2 with Ajax call.

```
textboxid.onkeydown = function(d) { 
    console.log( d.which ? d.which : window.event.keyCode); 
};
```